# Excel VBA Macro connecting to AWS RDS Aurora MySQL "Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005)"

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to fetch data from AWS RDS Aurora MySQL Database using Excel VBA.

Excel is running on Windows 10, all inbound IP allowed in AWS RDS, Excel MySQL Add-in installed, Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library enabled.

However I'm still getting the error code: Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005). I can connect using Workbench with no problem.

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection

oConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
"server=temporary.comal2agallf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;" & _
"uid=userid;" & _
"pwd=password;" & _
"database=database"

oConn.Open
```

Error Screenshot

[image: Error 1]

I have also tried changing the driver to:

```
driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0.11 Driver}
```

Error Screenshot

[image: Error 2]

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: `driver={SQL Server}`  - aren't you using MySQL?

Comment: Yes, that's why I also tried the "driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0.11 Driver}"
I don't have a technical background